# Sorting WTForms form.errors dict

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, wtforms

The forms.errors dict seems to be sorted on field name, and not on the 
order they are declared in the form itself.

E.g.

```
class ProductForm(Form): 
    code = TextField('Code', validators=[Required()]) 
    description = TextField('Description', validators=[Required(), Length(max=100)]) 
    amount = DecimalField('Amount', validators=[Required(), NumberRange(min=0.00, max=1000000.00)]) 
    vat_percentage = DecimalField('VAT %', validators=[Required(), NumberRange(min=0.00, max=100.00)]) 
    inactive_date = DateField('Inactive date', validators=[Optional()])
```

Which produces the form.errors like:

```
{'amount': ['Amount is required'], 'code': ['Code is invalid.'], 
'description': ['Description is required'], 'vat_percentage': ['VAT % is required']}
```

What I would like to do is print the the errors in the order as they are 
ordered in the form.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries are inherently unordered (in Python).  However, WTForms includes each field's errors on the field as well as the form and it *does* guarantee that the fields can be enumerated in declared order.  So rather than enumerating `form.errors` you can loop over `form` and then loop over each `field.errors` to get them in order:

```
for field in form:
    for error in field.errors:
        # Display error
```